# Text excerpts in body text

Tags: formatting, textarea

I have news items and want to limit the body to 100 characters. Is there a built-in function to create text excerpts?

Answer (score 2):

There used to be, not sure currently but I use this add on regularly; http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hacksaw

Does all that and more:)